# Select a body within a div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element (for example, a body) nested somewhere inside a div.. Something like:

```
<div class=wrapper>
..
..
<body>
</body>
</div>
```

How would I go about selecting the body with jQuery?

Comment: I don't *think* that's valid; or has something changed recently?

Comment: That's totally invalid markup

Comment: Why do you have that?! Is it a dead body?

Comment: So _that's_ where you hid the body...

Comment: @DavidThomas: Yes, something has changed. This is in preparation for HTML 6 (refer to http://www.ultraweaver.com/2010/04/html6-and-css4-announced-all-majors-browsers-on-board/)

Comment: Also you should add a <head></head> to that div too - otherwise it is a head-less body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As others have said - this doesn't look like valid HTML - I'm going to assume that you just gave that as an example as this technique can be used to find **any** type of element.

This should do the trick to locate the body tag -

```
$('div.wrapper').find('body')
```

When you don't specify in your selector that you are talking about a  class `.` or id `#` attribute - the whole string will be matched to the type of element.

The same could be done for -

- `<img>` tags -
  `$('div.wrapper').find('img')`
- `<a>` tags -
  `$('div.wrapper').find('a')`
- `<span>` tags -
  `$('div.wrapper').find('span')`
- etc...

Comment: `$("div.wrapper body")` should do it, altho performance-wise I don't know how that would differ to `.find()`. I really don't like the `body` within the `div` tho...

Comment: But still an example should have correct markup - I would always make sure my examples are correct as I know, otherwise, incorrect markup would be pointed to as the main cause of something not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML Markup is off, first of all.

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="body">
            ..
            ..
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Select it with `$('div.wrapper div.body')`

Thanks to ClarkeyBoy for pointing out my mistakes, fixed my post.

Comment: How would `$('div.wrapper body')` work when the markup is invalid in the first place and you're recommending to (correctly) put the `body` on the outside? Just use a `<div class='body'></div>` inside the wrapper and then `$('div.wrapper div.body')` to select it.

Comment: Whoops! Good catch. I wrote the second part first, went back and then fixed the html and forgot to change the script. Thanks bud.

Comment: Just seen the edit - you want the `<div class="wrapper"></div>` there still, around the `div.body`. You also want quotes around the 'body' (not required but good practice). (in case you're wondering, I just fixed it for you).

Comment: Thanks again, seems like I'm having an off-day with coding :P

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like valid HTML, but try this:

```
$('div.wrapper body')
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely that HTML isn't correct to have a body tag within a div? Unless it's inside an iframe?

However you could use this to select the body tag...

```
jQuery("div.wrapper body").whatever();
```

Comment: Oh FFS @Lix that was an only an example as in 'do whatever you want after this'. Please remove your down-vote.

Comment: Peoples experience levels on the site vary drastically - its not a good idea to post code that would throw errors.  Give a concrete example - `.hide()`, `.addClass()`... In our case `.remove()` might assist in making the markup valid again :P